# Short story with anthropomorphic rats, deadly addictive drug, noir crime setting: Spoiler alert

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, crime, morality

Seeking a pre-1980 (I believe) fantasy short story about crime and redemption. It’s written in the style of a gritty police procedural with the moral overtones of a classic detective story. The drug in question is overwhelmingly addictive with only one exposure and can corrupt even the most honorable people. The villain is a sentient, talking, rat crime boss/dealer, It’s never made clear how these rodents evolved or if they always have been present in this universe, I remember reading it a couple of times to try to figure it out, without success.

> The good cop who gets addicted overcomes the drug long enough to get the bad guy. The moral: This is what it means to be an honorable human versus a rat.

Comment: Thank you - meant an older story - I believe pre-1980. Will edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps "[Rat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_(short_story))" by James Patrick Kelly from 1986?

From the link:

> Rat is a criminal, **a drug runner and murderer**. He is selfish, amoral,
> vindictive. Yet the reader gets caught up in his plight and begins to
> empathize with him for two reasons. One is that stories do that to us:
> putting even a despicable character in the role of protagonist and
> filtering events through that character's perceptions automatically
> slants our responses toward that character, even against our moral
> judgment. The way the story is set up seduces us into rooting for Rat
> to get home, to outwit his pursuers, to make his score. The other
> reason is that **Rat is not a person but an animal, literally a rat, and
> everything he does is consistent with rat behavior: stealing, hiding,
> killing, surviving**.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the speed in which you find these gems. Going to find a copy  of the collection to buy. I never empathized with Rat, but it is a seductive story.

Comment: Glad I was able to help

Comment: For those interested, found it in this anthology: Think Like a Dinosaur: And Other Stories. One reviewer apparently was concerned because most of the stories were "dark", but I recognized a couple more that I have enjoyed - all very well written. Worth exploring.

Comment: "Appreciate the speed in which you find these gems."  -- keep the questions coming!

Comment: Thanks - these gems have been on my mind for a long time. I hope folks will be able to find the others. This is an amazing site> I hope also that I might be useful to others in their quests.